# How to set up Charles proxy for standalone Flash player during FlexUnit integration tests?

Tags: java, proxy, blazeds, amf, flexunit

I'd like to record the AMF traffic that happens during some of my Flex application unit tests.  I am using Maven/flexmojos to compile the unit tests.  I've installed Charles proxy and can get it to work from Firefox, but how can I get it to work from the standalone Flash player that flexmojos/FlexUnit invokes to run the integration tests to my BlazeDS backend Java server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After failing to find anyway to do this (on Ubuntu), I used the reverse-proxy capability of Charles to have it act only as a proxy for the BlazeSD server.  So far anyway, it seems very capable of reverse-proxying AMF traffic.   Nice.